# How to persist the selected value of Enum dropdown in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, filter, enums, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a global dropdown filter using Enum on my navbar. It works but the dropdown value goes back to default after filtering data. I want the selected value to continue persisting until changed by the user.

`FilterController.cs`

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(PostCategory? postCategory)
{
    List<Post> post;

    if (postCategory != null)
    {
        post = _context.Posts.Where(c => c.PostCategory == postCategory).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        post = _context.Posts.ToList();
    }

    _cache.Set("post", post);

    return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
}
```

`Filter.cshtml`

```html
<div class="col-4">
    <form class="w-75 ps-lg-5" asp-controller="Filter" asp-action="Index" id="category">
        <div class="input-group">
            <select class="form-control" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<PostCategory>()" name="postCategory" id="post-filter" >
                <option value="" selected>All</option>
            </select>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success me-2" type="submit">Filter</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

Here is what I have tried-

- `TempData.Keep()` doesn't meet my requirements. It only preserves the selected dropdown value for 2 page changes/refreshes.

```cs
...Code before
if (postCategory != null)
{
    TempData["selectedValue"] = postCategory;
    TempData.Keep();

    post = _context.Posts.Where(c => c.PostCategory == postCategory).ToList();
}
Code after...
```

- `Session` gives error- **CS0103:The name 'Session' doesnt exist in current context**.

```cs
...Code before
if (postCategory != null)
{
    Session["selectedValue"] = postCategory;

    post = _context.Posts.Where(c => c.PostCategory == postCategory).ToList();
}
Code after...
```

- `HttpContext.Session` gives error- **CS1955: Non-invocable member 'HttpContext.Session' cannot be used like a method.**

```cs
...Code before
if (postCategory != null)
{
    HttpContext.Session("selectedValue") = postCategory;

    post = _context.Posts.Where(c => c.PostCategory == postCategory).ToList();
}
Code after...
```

---

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the selected value to continue persisting until changed by the
> user.

You can use viewbag to store the selected value in it, and then judge it in the page, and return its value when ViewBag.PostCategory is not null. The following code can give you a reference:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(PostCategory? postCategory)
{
     List<Post> posts;

     if (postCategory != null)
     {
         posts = _context.Posts.Where(c => c.PostCategory == postCategory).ToList();
     }
     else
     {
         posts = _context.Posts.ToList();
     }
     _cache.Set("post", posts);     
     ViewBag.PostCategory = postCategory;    
     return View();
}
```

Page:

```
 <div class="col-4">
    <form class="w-75 ps-lg-5" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Index" id="category">
        <div class="input-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="postCategory" id="post-filter">
                <option value="">All</option>
                @foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PostCategory)))
                {
                    <!option value="@value" @(value.ToString() == ViewBag.PostCategory?.ToString() ? "selected" : "")>@value</!option>
                    
                }
            </select>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success me-2" type="submit">Filter</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

When start:

[image]

After choose data:

[image]
[image]

**Update**

If you want to maintain the selected value among non-logged-in users, sessionStorage is a good choice.When the page loads, it tries to fetch the previously saved selected value from the sessionStorage and apply it to the drop-down list. When the user changes the selection, it stores the new selected value in sessionStorage. If the user closes the browser tab or browser, the stored values are cleared.

```
<div class="col-4">
    <form class="w-75 ps-lg-5" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Index" id="category">
        <div class="input-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="postCategory" id="post-filter">
                <option value="">All</option>

                @foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PostCategory)))
                {
                   
                    <!option value="@value"  @(value.ToString() == ViewBag.PostCategory?.ToString() ? "selected" : "")>@value</!option>
                }
            </select>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success me-2" type="submit">Filter</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>

<script >
    $(document).ready(function () {
       
        var selectedValue = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedPostCategory');
        $('#post-filter').val(selectedValue);

        
        $('#post-filter').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            sessionStorage.setItem('selectedPostCategory', selectedValue);
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: your view code you provided is giving error in foreach:

I fixed it by codding `<!option value="@value @(value.ToString() == ViewBag.PostCategory?.ToString() ? "selected" : "")>@value</!option>` Now it stopped giving error but the code doesn't work as intended.

Comment: I've updated the code based on your prompt. If the error persists, please provide the relevant error information and I will do my best to help.

Comment: Thank you! it works as intended now but the selected value goes back to default after a page change. Ideally I would have used database for it but it would not work for  users that have not signed in into my website.

Comment: I've updated the code according to your description, you can take a look at the updated section.

Comment: your code it works but when first opening the website when no `Session Storage` value is stored, a blank is displayed in dropdown. I fixed it by writing `|| 'All'` in `var selectedValue = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedPostCategory') || 'All';`. Otherwise, the code works wonderfully. Thank you very much!